# vuejs how to increase the ratings of each game with a click on the span?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i want to be able to increae the rating of each game individually clicking on the span element. I try to access the property rating in the array but when i console log i get undefined. How do i increase the rating of each unique game on  a click?

I have added a method to handle the click event and i'm trying to increase the count of each rating but i seem to be getting it wrong.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Vue </title>
</head>

 <body>
 <div id="app">
 <div v-for="game in games" :key="game.name">
<h1>{{ game.name }} - <small>{{ game.console }}</small></h1>

<span v-for="star in game.rating" v-on:click="increment">❤️</span>

<div v-if="game.rating > 5">Wow, this game must be <b>REALLY</b> good</div>
 </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

  <script>
  const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data: {
      games: [
        { name: 'Super Mario 64', console: 'Nintendo 64', rating: 4 },
        { name: 'The Legend of Zelda Ocarina of Time', console: 'Nintendo 
        64', rating: 5 },
        { name: 'Secret of Mana', console: 'Super Nintendo', rating: 4 },
        { name: 'Fallout 76', console: 'Multiple', rating: 1 },
        { name: 'Super Metroid', console: 'Super Nintendo', rating: 6 }
      ],   
    },
    methods:{
        increment: function() {
        this.rating++ },
      }
    });
  </script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

i expect the ratings of each game to increase. for example super mario ratings to 5, the legend of Zelda Ocarina of time to 6 and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Vue</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(game, index) in games" :key="game.name"> <p>{{game}}</p>
    <h1>{{ game.name }} - <small>{{ game.console }}</small></h1>

    <span v-for="star in game.rating" v-on:click="increment(index)">❤️</span>

    <div v-if="game.rating > 5">Wow, this game must be <b>REALLY</b> good</div>
  </div>
</div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

  <script>
    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
        data: {
          games: [
            { name: 'Super Mario 64', console: 'Nintendo 64', rating: 4 },
            { name: 'The Legend of Zelda Ocarina of Time', console: 'Nintendo 64', rating: 5 },
            { name: 'Secret of Mana', console: 'Super Nintendo', rating: 4 },
            { name: 'Fallout 76', console: 'Multiple', rating: 1 },
            { name: 'Super Metroid', console: 'Super Nintendo', rating: 6 }
          ],   
        },
          methods: {
                increment: function(index) {
                    this.games[index].rating += 1;
                },
          }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great answer. I'd consider adding a brief description of the solution for context.

Comment: @Keith Gulbro with this answer i guess i need to create a project in cli to test the solution.

Comment: @Darragh Enright i will be waiting for the description.

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine With this solution, essentially you're just declaring the games variable as an array. After iterating through the games array inside the template we simply reference the index of the games item being clicked inside of the increment method as a parameter. Once the increment function is fired via the click handler we declared inside the template, we call the games array and the corresponding index of the games item we just clicked then increment the rating via the shorthand method which boils down to `this.games[index].rating = this.games[index] + 1`

Comment: Edit: `this.games[index].rating = this.games[index].rating + 1`

Comment: @Keith Gulbro thanks for the explanation i clearly get it now.